# How to construct an object that depends on the session to be loaded

Tags: php, laravel, oop, ioc-container

Let's suppose we have a site that shows a random list of 20 movies. Logged in users, however, can select their favorite movies, so those movies will be shown instead. This list of movies is shown both in the home page and in some other pages.

To follow the DRY principle, we could encapsulate this logic in its own class, and then inject this class wherever it is necessary to show the list of movies. This class will also have other methods that will be used throughout the application. For example, there is also a method to get one random movie.

The class could look like this (please note this is a simplified example):

```php
class MovieService
{

    /** @var Collection $movies */
    protected $movies;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->movies = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->favoriteMovies : $this->randomMovies();
    }

    public function getRandomMovies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->movies->random(20);
    }

    public function getOneRandom(): Movie {
        return $this->movies->random();
    }

    protected function randomMovies() {
        return Movie::inRandomOrder()->take(20)->get();
    }

}
```

**Note:** Please note that this is an example and that some things could be improved.

As this class could be used multiple times in the same request, it is a good idea to make it a **singleton** in the IoC container, so that the queries that are run when instantiated are not run more than once.

However, now we encounter a problem. We need this class in a private method in a controller. We could directly call the app container like `app()` or `App::make()` but we would like to avoid facades and global helpers with custom dependencies.

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    /** @var MovieService $movieService */
    protected $movieService;


    public function __construct(MovieService $movieService)
    {
        $this->movieService = $movieService;
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $movies = $this->getMovies();

        return view('home', compact('movies'));
    }

    protected function getMovies()
    {
        // Let's imagine there's some extra logic here so that we would actually need this method.
        return $this->movieService->getRandomMovies();
    }
}
```

We have found a problem. **A controller's constructor is run before the middleware pipeline**, which means that there's no session and, hence, no user identification. Now `Auth::check()` in `MovieService` is always returning `false`, so the default movies will always be shown.

What would you do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried calling the middleware in the constructor before instantiating `MovieService`?

Comment: **Related:** https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15072 - This was quite a hot topic issue when it was changed.

Comment: @Script47 Could you provide an example?

Comment: Before `$this->movieService = [...]` try adding `$this->middleware('<middleware-here>')`.

Comment: @Script47 I don't think that would do anything. The session middleware is always run, so there's no point of calling it like `$this->middleware()`, as the dependency is still in the controller and it would still be run before the middlewares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cleaner to not use the constructor of an object for logic, only for managing dependencies. Coincidentally this will also fix the issue you're having by moving the `Auth::check()` logic to your getter methods instead. Besides that you could also consider injecting the `AuthManager` instead of relying on the `Auth` facade, but that's just a sidenote.

```
class MovieService
{
    /** @var AuthManager  $auth */
    protected $auth;

    protected $movies;

    public function __construct(Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function getRandomMovies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->getMoviesForCurrentUser()->random(20);
    }

    public function getOneRandom(): Movie {
        return $this->getMoviesForCurrentUser()->random();
    }

    protected function randomMovies() {
        if ($this->movies === null) {
            $this->movies = Movie::inRandomOrder()->take(20)->get();
        }

        return $this->movies;
    }

    protected function getMoviesForCurrentUser() {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {
            return $this->auth->user->favoriteMovies;
        }

        return $this->randomMovies();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would fix it but then it creates a new problem. Every time one of those methods is called, a SQL query would be run to retrieve the movies. That's what I was trying to solve by first initializing the protected class attribute and then making the class a singleton. I completely agree with you that your way is way cleaner. I would like to know how to do it your way **without** running those queries multiple times.

Comment: You could adjust `randomMovies()` so it will store the retrieved results in memory (or any other form of caching) and return that if present. I've updated the code snippet with an example of doing so